# Dynamically generated onclick triggering the wrong event in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

So I have a 4 window frameset that is setup so that when the main content page loads, it changes the menu options on the left frame menu. Everything works correctly in FF and Chrome, but IE is giving me a problem. I think the problem lies in the javascript.

In IE, the menu items correctly change text, but when clicked on seem to trigger the wrong link. I have an example setup [here](http://www.olivestreet.com/test/home.htm).

Click on Customer Login on the left, then Sign Up in the main content area. From here, if you click on New Order/Browse, you'll arrive at the Create Order screen when using FF or Chrome. In IE, you'll find yourself back at the login screen.

I need help in getting the menu links on the left working correctly in IE7.